# Get all posts from a custom post type that are related to specific taxonomy with acf relationship field

Tags: relationship, advanced-custom-fields

I have one Custom post type called 'Adverts' in which I have a advanced custom field calling an image from each post. I then have a Custom post type called Listings with a taxonomy within it called 'Area' which has different terms for each region.

How can I call all the posts from Adverts that are only associated with one specific term (region)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this query - 'channel' being my taxonomy term and listing_area being my taxonomy. and 'associate_adverts' is the relationship field and 'adverts' is the post type I was pulling them from.

```
<?php if (has_term( 'channel', 'listing_area' )) { ?>


<?php
        $posts = get_posts(array(
'numberposts'   => 3,
'post_type'     => 'adverts',
'order_by' => 'title',
'order' => 'random',
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'      => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => 'associate_adverts',
        'value'     => '1822',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
    )
),
));

    ?>

  <?php //if it's returning the object

    foreach($posts as $advert){

        echo $advert->post_title; //member name

                 }?>

       <?php }
        ?>
```